# How can I add a panel in kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I can't right click in the desktop in kubuntu, so I can't add a panel (I remove all panels to start over the customization)

```
$ uname -vrpmios

Linux 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ plasmashell --version

plasmashell 5.12.9

$ kf5-config --version

Qt: 5.9.5
KDE Frameworks: 5.47.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

I've created another question regarding right-click issue: [Can't right click in desktop anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217665/cant-right-click-in-desktop-anymore)

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Right click in your desktop surface, choose add panel and appears a menu choose add default panel and that's all

Comment: That doesn't work, because I can't right click in my desktop surface, thank you