# Can't right click in desktop anymore

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I was customizing my kubuntu, when the right click stop working when I click in the Desktop

I already created another question regardings this issue:
[How can I add a panel in kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217631/how-can-i-add-a-panel-in-kubuntu?noredirect=1#comment2047347_1217631)

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2353 set 12  2019 plasma.desktop

$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
plasma

$ ls /usr/bin/*session
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session

$ head ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
[Containments][1]
activityId=4a35535f-6618-447a-ba7d-568df58dbc5a
formfactor=0
immutability=1
lastScreen=0
location=0
plugin=org.kde.plasma.folder
wallpaperplugin=org.kde.image

[Containments][1][Configuration]
```

```
$ cat ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc | pastebinit -b
Invalid arguments: option -b requires argument!

pastebinit v1.5
Reads on stdin for input or takes a list of filenames as parameters
    -E also print content to standard output
Optional arguments (not supported by all pastebins):
    -a <author:default is 'goncalo'>
    -b <pastebin url:default is 'paste.ubuntu.com'>
    -f <format of paste:default is 'text' (or from pastebin config)>
    -h This help screen
    -i <input file>
    -l List all supported pastebins
    -j <jabberid for notifications:default is ''>
    -m <permatag for all versions of a post:default is blank>
    -t <title of paste:default is blank>
    -P Private. Makes your paste hidden if possible
    -u <username> -p <password>
    -v Print the version number
    --verbose Verbose output to stderr

$ cat ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc | pastebinit -b pastebin.com
https://pastebin.com/A6AdLgDc
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You probably messed up the "mouse actions" in your Desktop Settings. There's a right-button >>> standard menu. You may have changed that.

Comment: If you haven't fixed your right-click as yet, please [edit] your question to include the output of `head  ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`.

Comment: @DKBose do you know where can I edit that?

Comment: What you posted didn't show what I was hoping to see. So please install `pastebinit` and then run `cat ~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc | pastebinit -b pastebin.com` and post the link here.